# Dynamic column name in WHERE clause using MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, orm, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I would like to write dynamic query where column name and column value might change in `WHERE` clause of SELECT statement.

So far I have this:

Mapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC
        "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="mypackage.PersonMapper">

    <resultMap id="personMap" type="Person">
        <id property="name" column="NAME"/>
        <id property="lastname" column="LASTNAME"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="selectByColumnName" resultType="Person" resultMap="personMap"><![CDATA[
        SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE #{columnName} = #{columnValue}
    ]]></select>
</mapper>
```

Mapper interface:

```
public interface PersonMapper {
    List<PersonModel> selectByColumnName(
            @Param("columnName") String column, @Param("columnValue") String value
    );
}
```

But when I call it `personMapper.selectByColumnName("NAME", "John")`, it does not work and gives me empty result. If I replace my SELECT query in Mapper.xml with query where I specify column name like this :

`SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = #{columnValue}`

then it works fine and returns all persons with the given dynamic columnValue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `${}` string substitution:

```
    <select id="selectByColumnName" resultType="Person" resultMap="personMap"><![CDATA[
        SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE ${columnName} = #{columnValue}
    ]]></select>
```